# indentation with composed and piped functions

Tags: f#

I'm trying to get this block of code right, getting it readable by splitting into different lines, can use some help here.

```
list |> Array.iter ( fun data -> data.Href |> ( regex.Match >> ( fun m ->
          let result = {ArticleModule.defaultArticle with publicationId = m.Groups.[1].Value; entityType = m.Groups.[3].Value; entityName = m.Groups.[4].Value; version = m.Groups.[5].Value}
) ) )
```

**Edit**

A shortest form perhaps to help further on how to break this in separate lines.

```
list |> Array.iter ( fun data -> data.Href |> ( regex.Match >> ( fun m -> Console.WriteLine m ) ) )
```

**Attempt 1**

```
list |> Array.iter (fun data -> (data.Href) 
     |> regex.Match // squiggly lines here
     |> (fun m -> Console.WriteLine m))
```

Comment: A quick & easy way to clean this up is to extract some named functions from those nested lambdas.

Comment: got it, that's one option, but what's the rule when it comes to sequences of lambdas

Comment: I've noticed examples with aligning pipe symbols on separate lines and that works, but I've got a mix of pipes and composition here

Comment: see the edit please for a short form in case code noise is distracting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, since you ask how to indent this code, I'll point you to https://github.com/dungpa/fantomas/blob/master/docs/FormattingConventions.md, which is an excellent reference that you should probably bookmark. 3/4 of the way down that page you will find https://github.com/dungpa/fantomas/blob/master/docs/FormattingConventions.md#pipeline-operators which suggests that sequences of pipeline operators should be indented with the pipeline directly under the data that is flowing through the pipeline:

```
let result =
    data
    |> step1
    |> Array.filter (fun x -> x == "something")
    |> step3
```

And so on.

Now, to apply this advice to your situation.

First, the squiggly lines in your attempt 1 are because on the `regex.Match` line, you're still inside the `fun data -> ...` lambda. All lines in F# should line up vertically with the thing they belong to (vague language because this is a general rule that applies to many situations). Here, that would look like:

```
list |> Array.iter (fun data -> data.Href
                                |> regex.Match
                                |> (fun m -> Console.WriteLine m))
```

Now, that looks kind of ugly to me. So I would split out the `fun data -> ...` lambda into its own function:

```
let handleOneItem data =
    data.Href
    |> regex.Match
    |> (fun m -> Console.WriteLine m)

list |> Array.iter handleOneItem
```

Much nicer.

Now, let's look at your original code, where the final lambda in the pipeline was not calling `Console.WriteLine`, but was creating a record. There's one error in that code, which is that a `let` statement *does nothing* in and of itself. What you probably wanted to write was:

```
fun m ->
    let result = {ArticleModule.defaultArticle with publicationId = m.Groups.[1].Value; entityType = m.Groups.[3].Value; entityName = m.Groups.[4].Value; version = m.Groups.[5].Value}
    result
```

Which in turn can simply be turned into:

```
fun m ->
    {ArticleModule.defaultArticle with publicationId = m.Groups.[1].Value; entityType = m.Groups.[3].Value; entityName = m.Groups.[4].Value; version = m.Groups.[5].Value}
```

And now, I would recommend taking that long record and splitting it across multiple lines (see https://github.com/dungpa/fantomas/blob/master/docs/FormattingConventions.md#records for details), like so:

```
fun m ->
    { ArticleModule.defaultArticle with
        publicationId = m.Groups.[1].Value
        entityType = m.Groups.[3].Value
        entityName = m.Groups.[4].Value
        version = m.Groups.[5].Value }
```

I'd probably make this its own named function:

```
let mkRecord m =
    { ArticleModule.defaultArticle with
        publicationId = m.Groups.[1].Value
        entityType = m.Groups.[3].Value
        entityName = m.Groups.[4].Value
        version = m.Groups.[5].Value }
```

Now let's look again at the full code:

```
let mkRecord m =
    { ArticleModule.defaultArticle with
        publicationId = m.Groups.[1].Value
        entityType = m.Groups.[3].Value
        entityName = m.Groups.[4].Value
        version = m.Groups.[5].Value }

let handleOneItem data =
    data.Href
    |> regex.Match
    |> mkRecord

list |> Array.iter handleOneItem
```

There's just one more mistake here, which is that `Array.iter` is the wrong type. `Array.iter` wants you to hand it a function that returns `unit` (i.e., returns nothing meaningful). Any function that returns nothing meaningful is clearly being called for its side effects, not its return value. Since `mkRecord` returns a value and has no side effects, you want `Array.map` instead. So the **final** version of your code would be:

```
let mkRecord m =
    { ArticleModule.defaultArticle with
        publicationId = m.Groups.[1].Value
        entityType = m.Groups.[3].Value
        entityName = m.Groups.[4].Value
        version = m.Groups.[5].Value }

let handleOneItem data =
    data.Href
    |> regex.Match
    |> mkRecord

list |> Array.map handleOneItem
```

Comment: Hold on, I just noticed that you intend your `Array.iter` to be the whole thing. I'll edit my answer to reflect your intent.

Comment: we can decompose as long as I've the intended results, I want `data.Href` (it's a `string`) to go to `regex.Match` and then display result of regex. This for each item in the array. I think that's where I'm confused too between the two, i.e. either iterate the whole thing or split them into parts into each line

Comment: Edited my answer completely now that I've seen that your original code was trying to create a record, not just call `Console.WriteLine`.

Comment: And BTW, if you are calling `Console.WriteLine` then `Array.iter` is the right function to use. It's only if you're returning a value that you should be using `Array.map`.

Comment: thanks for putting both approaches, ugly and with func, the actual intent to create list of records (after going through `regex` and `mkRecord`), appreciate if you can add that piece, so I'd be returning a value, that is list of records, `Array.map` then?

Comment: I already added that piece; that's my final suggested code that uses `Array.map`.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with using a `for` loop. If what you do in the end is an imperative operation like printing to the console, then using `for` loop clearly indicates that this is what you do:

```
for data in list do
  let m = regex.Match data.Href
  Console.WriteLine m
```

From your other example, it looks like you are trying to use `Array.map` to create a new array. The answer from @rmunn covers this nicely, but again, note that you do not need to do everything using `|>`. It is often easier to use `let` binding:

```
list |> Array.map (fun data ->
  let m = regex.Match data.Href
  { ArticleModule.defaultArticle with
      publicationId = m.Groups.[1].Value
      entityType = m.Groups.[3].Value
      entityName = m.Groups.[4].Value
      version = m.Groups.[5].Value })
```